# Strange number comparison behaviour in Oracle 11.2.0.3.0 with existsNode

Tags: sql, database, oracle, casting, oracle11g

I'm trying to select all rows of a table where one column contains a specific xml-value.
It is working fine when I run the query against my local database or the one of our internal testservers. However, on the customers testserver, the query does not return any rows.

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE existsnode(...) = 1
```

I found out that if I quote the comparison value, it works on all databases:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE existsnode(...) = '1'
```

I'd like to understand why this happens and what a good solution for this issue would be.
The database version is 11.2.0.3.0 on all systems.

**EDIT:**
I did some further research and found out that the returned datatype is actually a number, as stated in the Oracle documentation.

```
SELECT dump(existsNode(...)) FROM product;
```

Returns "Typ=2, Len=1: 128" on all databases.

However, I have some double quotes inside of the existsnode query string, and these double quotes seem to get lost on the databases with which I am having the strange comparison problem:

```
SELECT existsnode(xmltype(attributes), '/attrs/attr[@name="SomeFlag"]') FROM product;
```

On the databases where the query works, I get the following result as the column name:

```
EXISTSNODE(XMLTYPE(ATTRIBUTES), '/ATTRS/ATTR[@NAME="SOMEFLAG"]')
```

On the other databases I get

```
EXISTSNODE(XMLTYPE(ATTRIBUTES), '/ATTRS/ATTR[@NAME=SOMEFLAG]')
```

Comment: http://www.sql.ru/forum/258743/to-number-and-nls-numeric-characters

Comment: mmm, maybe this is why existsnode is deprecated? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions057.htm#SQLRF00637

Comment: If your output is actually a direct copy you have a different Problem: The Second argument is missing a closing single quote! Without it a big part of the command will be interpretet as a test-literal - it should be `EXISTSNODE(XMLTYPE(ATTRIBUTES), '/ATTRS/ATTR[@NAME="SOMEFLAG"]')` - Otherwise you get unexpected results akin to SQL-Injection - then the second query could somehow work, because '1' provides a closing single quote...

Comment: The output was not a direct copy, I forgot to add the closing quote. I edited my question. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: hehehe, if its not broken you haven't used enough XML.

Answer (score 2):

Check out document number, Doc ID 14087914.8 (Bug Number 14087914) on support.oracle.com.

Per the document, try to following to see if the results no produce what you are expecting.

```
alter session set "_fix_control"='9569678:off
```

Your other option, involves upgrading to 11.2.0.4.